# UnknownHostException again!

Tags: java

I posted one question previously and all of them answered that there is some problem with DNS but i changed my DNS to many addressed and now i have the most reliable, google DNS :-

```
8.8.8.8
```

Still i get the same UnknownHostException. What can be the problem? This is my code :-

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = db.parse("http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/india");
```

Infact if i pass address as something very common like :- http://google.com i still get the same error. Please help me :(. I have my submissions tomorrow.

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT** : If i type the same address in my mozilla, it works great. So, i am sure that there is no DNS problem.

**2nd EDIT** :- I found this link http://www.ehow.com/how_4747553_fix-unknownhostexception-java-applications-ubuntu.html

But when i run the command

```
sudo apt-get install lib32nss-mdns
```

i get package not found.

Somebody even mentioned :-

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

But where do i write this statement of Djava?

I am using Netbeans 6.8 to run my web application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need a proxy.

If so, try passing it in the command line

```
 java  -Dhttp.proxyHost=your.proxy.server  -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 YourJavaApp
```

**EDIT** to set this information ( -Dhttp...etc etc )  in netbeans use the Run menu:

Run\Set Project Configuration\Customize\Run

Should look like this:

[run http://img227.imageshack.us/img227/7903/netbeansy.png](http://img227.imageshack.us/img227/7903/netbeansy.png)

Use the one that says: *Virtual machine options*  and type:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=your.proxy.server  -Dhttp.proxyPort=80
```

Or as per your update type:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Comment: Can you just tell me where should i write this line `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` in Netbeans?